# JSON array keyerror in Python

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, function

I'm fairly new to Python programming and am attempting to extract data from a JSON array. Below code results in an error for

```
js[jstring][jkeys]['5. volume'])
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json

def DailyData(symb):

    url = https://www.alphavantage.co/queryfunction=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

    stockdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = stockdata.read().decode()

    try:
        js = json.loads(data)
    except:
        js = None

    jstring = 'Time Series (Daily)'

    for entry in js:
        i = js[jstring].keys()

        for jkeys in i:
            return (jkeys,
                js[jstring][jkeys]['1. open'],
                js[jstring][jkeys]['2. high'],
                js[jstring][jkeys]['3. low'],
                js[jstring][jkeys]['4. close'],
                js[jstring][jkeys]['5. volume'])

print('volume',DailyData(symbol)[5])
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error message/traceback?

Comment: What error are you getting? `TypeError`, `KeyError`, `SyntaxError`, ...? The exact error you're getting can drastically change the problem

Comment: The error message is: KeyError: 'Time Series (Daily)'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the reason for the error is because the returned data from the URL is a bit more hierarchical than you may realize.  To see that,  print out js (I recommend using a jupyter notebook):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl
import json
import sqlite3

url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo"

stockdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = stockdata.read().decode()

js = json.loads(data)
js
```

[image]

You can see that js (now a python dict) has a "Meta Data" key before the actual time series begins. You need to start operating on the dict at that key.

Having said that,  to get the data into a table like structure (for plotting,  time series analysis, etc),  you can use pandas package to read the dict key directly into a dataframe. The pandas DataFrame constructor accepts a dict as input.  In this case,  the data was transposed,  so the T at the end rotates it (try with and without the T and you will see it.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(js['Time Series (Daily)']).T 

df
```

[image]

Added edit...  You could get the data into a dataframe with a single line of code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo"

data = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url).json()['Time Series (Daily)']).T
```

DataFrame:  The contructor from Pandas to make data into a table like structure

requests.get(): method from the requests library to fetch data..

.json(): directly converts from JSON to a dict

['Time Series (Daily)']: pulls out the key from the dict that is the time series

.T: transposes the rows and columns.

[image]

Good luck!

**Following code worked for me**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json

def DailyData(symb):

    # Your code was missing the ? after query
    url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol={}&apikey=demo".format(symb)

    stockdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = stockdata.read().decode()

    js = json.loads(data)

    jstring = 'Time Series (Daily)'

    for entry in js:
        i = js[jstring].keys()

        for jkeys in i:
            return (jkeys,
                js[jstring][jkeys]['1. open'],
                js[jstring][jkeys]['2. high'],
                js[jstring][jkeys]['3. low'],
                js[jstring][jkeys]['4. close'],
                js[jstring][jkeys]['5. volume'])

# query multiple times, just to print one item?
print('open',DailyData('MSFT')[1])
print('high',DailyData('MSFT')[2])
print('low',DailyData('MSFT')[3])
print('close',DailyData('MSFT')[4])
print('volume',DailyData('MSFT')[5])
```

**Output:**

open 99.8850

high 101.4300

low 99.6700

close 101.1600

volume 19234627

Without seeing the error,  it's hard to know what exact problem you were having.

Comment: Thank you Randall. Is here a way to adjust my code so that it works? 0 to 4 index seems to work fine on print('volume',DailyData(symbol)[]), with only 5 throwing the keyerror.